# Javascript: write condition regex for multiple strings

Tags: javascript, regex

I want to write a regex for the following strings to include all strings:

```
B9966
ch6258
028
chIRZ170
IRZ170

B8966A
BA966C
```

The **OUTPUT** should be as follows:

```
966
6258
028
170
170

966A
BA966C
```

**Conditions**:

1. If you look at b9966, you see that its output is 966. it means If the string started with one character, the next digit of the character is not part of the output.
2. If the string is an integer, the whole string is output.
3. I want the output of B8966A to be like this 966A.
4. Otherwise, if the previous three conditions do not exist, all string digits are returned as output.

I wanted to write with conditions in regex **(ie:** `(?(?condition)then|else)`**)** but found that javascript does not support conditions.
For example, the following solution works fine, but I'm looking for a more professional regex:

```
^\d+.|(?<=^\D{1}\d)\d+.|(?<=^\D{2,})\d+.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For your example data, you can remove either an uppercase case followed by a single digit, or remove all non digits.

```
[A-Z]\d|[^\d\n]+
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/nyYaaR/1)

```js
const regex = /[A-Z]\d|[^\d\n]+/g;
[
  "B9966",
  "ch6258",
  "028",
  "chIRZ170",
  "IRZ170"
].forEach(s => console.log(s.replace(regex, '')));
```

**Edit**

For the updated examples, you could start the match with a non digit followed by a digit, or match 1+ non digits:

```
\b(?:[^\d\n]\d|[^\d\n]+)
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/lF6xOj/1)

To not touch the last example, you can use a negative lookahead:

```
\b(?:[^\d\n]\d|(?![A-Z]{2}\d)[^\d\n]+)
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/QXIR18/1)

```js
const regex = /\b(?:[^\d\n]\d|(?![A-Z]{2}\d)[^\d\n]+)/;
[
  "B9966",
  "ch6258",
  "028",
  "chIRZ170",
  "IRZ170",
  "B8966A",
  "BA966C"
].forEach(s => console.log(s.replace(regex, '')));
```

Comment: there is another condition, I want the output of B8966A to be like this 966A.

Comment: I write ```let regex = /[\D]\d|([^\d\n]+\D)/g;``` it is correctly?

Comment: @Garme It depends on the rules for the whole string. You can for example list all the rules that should remove parts: https://regex101.com/r/0c8Acq/1

Comment: @Garme Or match all the parts `(?<!\b[A-Z])\d+[A-Z]*|\b[A-Z][A-Z]\d\w+` https://regex101.com/r/af7Xpb/1

Comment: This also works properly ```\b([\D]\d|[^\d\n]+)```

Comment: @Garme That would also work, but not that it would also match `BA` in  `BA966C` In that case, you can also omit the capture group, see https://regex101.com/r/lF6xOj/1

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/238746/discussion-between-garme-and-the-fourth-bird).

Comment: ```(?<!^\D)\d+.*``` see https://regex101.com/r/Av8pEq/1

Answer (score 1):

Another regex can be used:

```
(?<!^\D)\d+.*
```

In the above regex, the Negative Lookbehind is used, ie if each character did not start with `\D` before and is matched with the character `\d` after.
Result: https://regex101.com/r/Av8pEq/1